# Exponent of Projection (T^2=T)

Tags: exponentiation, projective-geometry

T:V->V is a linear transformation, also it's a projection, i.e. T^2=T.

Find e^T.

I thought of using the fact that if T=T^2 then e^T=e^(T^2) but I guess that doesn't work because exponent is a sum of endless "numbers"
maybe the fact that T^k = T for every k may help ?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have by a simple induction $T^n=T$ so

$$\exp (T)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{T^n}{n!}=I+T\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n!}=I+(e-1)T$$

Comment: Good to see you. How's the grading coming along? ;-)

Comment: Yikes! (the best grade!)...And whoa! It sounds like you "ran" a marathon (of grading)!

Answer (score 1):

Use the series representation of the exponential
$$
e^T = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac1{n!} T^n,
$$
from $T=T^2$ you can deduce $T^n=T$ for all $n$.

Comment: I know that already but how does this help ? I ave to find e^T

Comment: see the other answer :)